# How to disable "auto cd" in zsh with oh-my-zsh

Tags: shell, zsh, oh-my-zsh

Googling this didn't show up any results. Here's what I mean: I have a binary file named `x` in my path (not the current folder, but it is in the `PATH`), and *also* a folder with the same name in the current working directory. If I type `x`, I want the binary to execute, but instead it cd's into that folder. How do I fix this?

Comment: The worst part of this "feature" is that subdirectories take precedence over binaries on the path. This is not how any conventional shell works!

Answer (score 76, accepted):

## TL; DR

Add this line to your `~/.zshrc`:

```
unsetopt autocd
```

#### AUTO_CD Option and howto find it

First of all the option you are looking for is AUTO_CD.
You can easily find it by looking up `man zshoptions`. Use your pagers search function, usually you press <kbd>/</kbd> and enter the keyword. With <kbd>n</kbd> you jump to the next occurrence. This will bring up the following:

```
[..]
   Changing Directories
       AUTO_CD (-J)
              If  a  command is issued that can't be executed as a normal command, and the command is the name of a directory, perform the cd command to that directory.
[..]
```

The option can be unset using `unsetopt AUTO_CD`.

#### Turning it properly off

You are using oh-my-zsh which is described as

> "A community-driven framework for managing your zsh configuration"
> Includes 120+ optional plugins (rails, git, OSX, hub, capistrano, brew, ant, macports, etc), ...

So the next thing is to find out, how to enable/disable options according to the framework.

The [readme.textile file](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/blob/master/README.textile) states that the prefered way to enable/disable plugins would be an entry in your .zshrc: `plugins=(git osx ruby)`
Find out which plugin uses the AUTO_CD option. As discovered from the manpage it can be invoked via the -J switch or AUTO_CD. Since oh-my-zsh is available on github, searching for it will turn up the file `lib/theme-and-appearance.zsh`.
If you don't want to disable the whole plugin "theme-and-appearance", put a `unsetopt AUTO_CD` in your .zshrc. Don't modify the files of oh-my-zsh directly, because in case you are updating the framework, your changes will be lost.

#### Why executables are not invoked directly

Your third question is howto execute a binary directly:
You have to execute your binary file via a path, for example with a prefixed `./` as in `./do-something`. This is some kind of a security feature and should not be changed.
hing of  plugging in an USB stick, mounting it and having a look on it with `ls`. If there is a executable called `ls` which deletes your home directory, everything would be gone, since this would have overwritten the order of your $PATH.

If you have commands you call repeatedly, setting up an alias in your .zshrc would be a common solution.

Comment: Thank you very much! What I needed was the `unsetopt auto_cd` line (I did explicitly mention that the executable _is_ in my path though; nevertheless, the explanation might help other users figure things out).

Comment: Thank you for the thorough answer and providing details on how you found the information (thus helping others find information like this on their own in the future).

Comment: Your last paragraph makes no sense. The OP is asking about a binary in their `PATH` environment variable which they want to take precedence over autocd. It has nothing to do with shell script's inability to run an executable from a path without specifying either `./` or `/`.

Comment: The first link to the readme does not work. [Here](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh) it is. Furthermore, the OMZ `lib` directory has nothing todo with `plugins`.Regarding the question and as you said, the correct command is `unsetopt`.

Comment: This is one of the least useful technically correct answers I've ever seen. So much *completely* unnecessary and useless context when you could have just said "`lib/theme-and-appearance.zsh` is responsible for turning that feature on. Add `unsetopt AUTO_CD` to your .zshrc to disable it."

Answer (score 28):

This worked for me:

```
unsetopt autocd
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. No bullshit included.

Comment: If you are using oh-my-bash then `shopt -u autocd` command for you.